# Correlation id Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-project

I have some problem with my Sharepoint 2010. When I try select from existing assignments, I getting the following error:

[image]

I try investigate this in event viewer, I tried using PowerShell to find out what the error is in the form of. I used this

```
get-splogevent | ?{$_.Correlation -eq "CORRELATION ID"} | select Area, Category, Level, EventID, Message | Format-List > C:\Awesome.log
```

however, did not get any result, Do you have any idea how to fix it.

Regards
Mick